# Не открывается файл после чтения из закрытой книги

Tags: excel, vba

Необходимо было считать данные из другой закрытой книги, ДВССЫЛ читает только при другой открытой книге, в сети был найден способ через UDF

```
Function Get_Value_From_Close_Book(sWb As String, sShName As String, sAddress As String)
Dim vData, objCloseBook As Object
Set objCloseBook = GetObject(sWb)
vData = objCloseBook.Sheets(sShName).Range(sAddress).Value
objCloseBook.Close False
Get_Value_From_Close_Book = vData
End Function
```

Значение считывается, но после использования данной функции, книга из которой читаем не открывается(просто открывается новый экземпляр excel). Каким образом предотвратить поломку файла после работы функции?

=Get_Value_From_Close_Book("D:\temp\"&C2&".xlsx","Лист1","A1")

C2="Data"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Могу посоветовать Power Query. Офигенная штука, о которой я, к своему стыду, узнал всего год назад. Позволяет вытянуть хоть из файлов, хоть из БД, хоть с сайтов что угодно.
В частности, использую для консолидации отчетов по продажам из 40 регионов: 40 файлов закидал в папку, обновил подключение и всё - результаты загружены!